# How to reconstruct a list with punctuation into a sentence? In python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list e.g. `['hello',', ','how','are','you','?']` and i want it to become `"hello, how are you?"`
Is there anyway at doing this?

I should also note that i am opening this from a text document, using the code:

```
    with gzip.open('task3.txt.gz', 'r+') as f:
    reconstruct = f.readline()
    reconstruct2 = f.readline()
    reconstruct3 = f.readline()
    reconstruct4 = f.readline()
    f.close()
```

So my lists come out as `b'["hello", ",", "how", "are", "you", "?"]\n'` could this be linked to the fact i saved them with new lines?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually properly *detokenize* the list of tokens back into a sentence with an [`nltk`'s `moses` detokenizer](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1282) (available in the `nltk` trunk at the moment - has not been released yet):

```
In [1]: from nltk.tokenize.moses import MosesDetokenizer

In [2]: l = ['hello', ', ', 'how', 'are', 'you', '?']

In [3]: detokenizer = MosesDetokenizer()

In [4]: detokenizer.detokenize(l, return_str=True)
Out[4]: u'hello, how are you?'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you're looking for **join()**:

```
>>> a = ['hello',', ','how','are','you','?']
>>> " ".join(a)
'hello ,  how are you ?'
```

Note, that the content of quotation marks will be inserted in between of your words. So you need to decide, if you want to use " " (which will insert space also between "you" and "?", for example) or "" - but insert space at the end of each word (your array should look like that: ['Hello', ', ', 'how ', 'are ', 'you', '?'])

Comment: I think that's exactly the question - how to properly reconstruct the sentence with no extra spaces.

Comment: Then I think there shouldn't be any extra spaces at all - this example contains one for "," - which is kind of misleading what OP is really looking for.